# C++ shared_ptr std::bind and std::function

Tags: c++, shared-ptr, std-function, boost-signals2

I have the following:

class `B` listens to a `boost::signal2` of class `C` and when triggered will execute a callback given by class `A` and that executes a method in class `A`

`A`, `B` and `C`, `D` are all `std::shared_ptr`.

The problem is that when class `D` releases the pointer to class `B`, `B` is not being deleted because of the signal handler. Even if I call disconnect on the `boost::connection` I have the same problem.

Any Idea how I can fix that ?

Comment: Can you show us some code?

Comment: Yes, this is not any use without sufficient code for people to understand what is going on internally.

Comment: I think what you want is a [`std::weak_pointer`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/weak_ptr) for the signal handler, but I agree that having code would make this easier to understand.

Comment: Here is a part of the code that can be usefull:https://gist.github.com/bend/c923187223e0ade3117168bee874feea

Comment: The weird thing is that I don't see any call of the destructor (I've put a cout in the desctructor) but I don't see any leak of the object in valgrind...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So the problem was due to a `shared_ptr` cycle.

Class `A` was passing to class `B` an `std::function` that holds a `shared_ptr` to class `A`, so class `A` was never being deleted.

eg. `B.route(std::bind(&A::myFunc, shared_from_this()));`

I fixed it with a lambda function and a weak_ptr in class `A`:

```
std::weak_ptr<A> wp = shared_from_this();
  A.route(std::bind([wp]() {
   auto p = wp.lock();
   if(wp)
     wp->myFunc();
}));
```

That way my function `myFunc` is only called if A is still valid.